# Asus MeMo Pad - Debug for Android apps

Tags: android, driver, adb

I just received a new Asus MeMo Pad (10") from work, in order to debug our Android apps on it, However, I can't seems to manage to install a suitable driver for it (it's pretty new, released just a few weeks ago)

In the Windows (8) device manager, I see `Asus Android Composite ADB Interface` with the yellow warning sign next to it, and when I'm trying to update the driver, both from the internet and from the `SDK` dir as suggested by Google, it fails.

I tried:

- Looking through Asus's website for drivers
- Installing `Asus Sync` - It doesn't recognize my tablet.
- Using old Asus pads driver - No luck

My guess is that the it's too new and still doesn't have available drivers (though it seems weird that Asus would release the tablet without drivers).

Is there any work around this?

When I'm connecting it to my PC, I can see its files, but I can't debug (using `adb devices` shows an empty list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you can try to do is manually install the driver. When you use the install driver prompt, tell it to scan the USB driver folder in the SDK, and select the option to pick a driver from a list. Select the Composite Device option (It'll be either ADB Composite Device or Android Composite Device,  I can't recall which and I don't have my Windows devbox at the moment) and see if the driver will successfully install. I've done that for my Galaxy Tab 10.1 and LG Optimus G, and gotten ADB functionality that way, so it may work for your MeMo Pad.