# No driver for Asus MeMO Pad to do application debug using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, driver, device-driver

I have the same problem like in the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029581/asus-memo-pad-debug-for-android-apps)-

I got a new Asus Memo Pad for debugging my android application in eclipse while running the
application in the Asus Memo Pad. But when I go to devise chooser in eclipse, I does not find my devise in the list. I know this is because I am not having the appropriate usb driver installed for my Asus Memo Pad but I didn't found its driver in the asus site and also after googling a lot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked by installing `PdaNet Desktop` application on my personal computer. Although I already switched on `USB debugging` but that was not working other than trying various unsuccessful options.

Answer (score 4):

I found one solution.
Please go to setting
In the setting -> System -> About

It will display many item about this pad. Please click the version item continually. Then it will show a message " You become a developer". The it will appear a new item "developer option", enter this item and enable "USB Debbger".

Finally, you can debug on this pad!!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 I let Windows Update find the right driver for USB debugging. Connect the device via USB, enable debugging from the device's settings and configure Update to get the driver automatically.
I couldn't find the driver on Asus's or Microsoft's website directly.

Answer (score 1):

The developer options are hidden in many devices

-> Go in `Setting` -> `About` -> Tap on `Build Version` 10 times

Following these steps you have enabled developer options. Go back in setting menu and now you can see the developer menu, here you have to check

```
enable USB debugging
```

That's all

Answer (score 1):

```
Settings / About / Software Info / Build number
```

And then click several time on "Build number" , a toaster will say that you're about to switch to developer mode.

I don't know how to switch it back off

This was tested on Android 4.4.2 Model K01E 
Built date 20140526

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: Check settings, choose on the list below Developer option, then you have to enable the option and select stay awake, USB debugging. It normally works!

Answer (score 0):

I got the driver by doing the following:

I enabled USB Debugging on my tablet and I connected it to my computer. As everyone else, Eclipse wouldn't find my tablet.

I then went to:
`Control Panel` -> `Device Manager`. Under `"Other devices"`, my tablet was listed as `ASUS Android Composite ADB Interface` (Search for it, if it's not under "Other Devices"). I left clicked on the tablet and selected `Update Driver Software`. I let Windows search automatically for updated driver software. Once the driver was installed, I restarted the computer and the tablet was then viewable under my devices in Eclipse.

More information on the Google Android site [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).