# Android : No USB Driver to detect my Android Phone - Download App

Tags: android

I have an Android Mobile phone but even after installing Universal USB driver my system is not able to detect the phone.

I have an Android application developed using Android SDK - how can I download the app to my mobile. I have an SD card - but which  file should I copy on it?

Comment: Usually you get the driver from the manufacturer of your phone.

Comment: Sorry I tried a lot but I was unable to get it identified by my system. So which files I should copy to my SD card of the Andriod APP developed by Android SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To detect phone** -

See my SO post on [No driver for application debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880961/no-driver-for-asus-memo-pad-to-do-application-debug-using-eclipse).

Generally, if the only purpose is to install the application on your mobile device then 
you just need to copy the generated .apk file of your application to your mobile device
via any way (USB, email, etc.) and simply run it there.

The location of .apk file is your workspace application bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to enable USB debugging depend on the version of Android running on the target device, as indicated in the following table:

**Developer Options on Gingerbread (Android 2.3):**

Settings> Applications> Development> USB Debugging

**Developer Options on ICS (Android 4.0):**

Settings> Developer Options> USB Debugging

**Developer Options on JB (Android 4.1):**

Settings> Developer Options> USB Debugging

If you have recently upgraded your device to Android 4.2 Jelly Bean or have bought a new device with 4.2 or higher pre-installed, do not be surprised if you find the  ”Developer Options” missing.

**Enable the USB Debugging option under Settings > Developer options.**

1. On the device, go to **Settings > About** .
2. Tap the Build number seven times to make **Settings > Developer options** available.
3. Then enable the **USB Debugging** option.

Comment: It is A Yxtel G905 having version 4.1.1. I have enabled the USB debugging options already

Comment: In Windows 7 try the following.
Right Click Computer then Manage
Expand Android phone at the top of the list
Right click Android ADB Interface then Update Driver Software
Browse my computer for driver software
Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
Choose USB Composite Device then next

Comment: Thanks but I have already made the same configuration